# "Internal Compiler Error" when using g++ inside Docker

Tags: docker, g++

I am trying to compile my C++ project with g++, under the Makefile build system. However, during compilation, the following error message randomly occurs:

```
random source file A.cpp:xxx:xx: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
   random location
          ^~~~~~~~
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

If I retry the `make` command, the `A.cpp` error goes away, but it may re-appear at another random location in `B.cpp`, and therefore I need to reiterate the process until the compilation completes.

I have googled for this issue and it seems that (according to [this](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/issues/3781) GitHub thread) that OOM is the reason why this happens. However, I have tried the following solutions in *docker-compose* but none of them can guarantee a successful one-time compilation:

- Single-threaded `make` build (although ideally I would like to do `make -j $(nproc)`).
- Setting memory size and memory swap size: `mem_limit: 8g`, `memswap_limit: 100g`
- Setting `shm_size`: `shm_size: 8g`

I am sure that 8G memory is sufficient to compile the project, as I am able to do it natively without using docker, but introducing docker causes the above error to happen randomly. May I know how I should solve the problem?

P.S. I am using docker 19.03.8 and g++ 7.5.0

Answer (score -2):

It might be a shared memory limitation? You can increase shared memory size from the default 64M like:

```
docker run -it --shm-size=512m
```

or with docker-compose:

```
shm_size: 512M
```

see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)